# IIS application Build failure in ElasticBeanstalk AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying IIS application into .net framework. 64bit Windows Server 2016 v2.3.2 running IIS 10.0"

I kept getting this error I have no answer to. Please help

```
AWSDeployment.log:

2020-02-20 22:54:26,203 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Reading configuration from c:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\config\containerconfiguration
2020-02-20 22:54:26,343 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Exception during deployment.
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedException: Object of type 'package' and path 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' cannot be created.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The Zip package 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' could not be loaded. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip'.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileStreamEx.CreateInstance(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare, Nullable`1 fileLength)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipFile.Load()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String path)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 106
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 56
2020-02-20 22:54:26,360 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Unexpected Exception: System.Exception: Exception during deployment. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedException: Object of type 'package' and path 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' cannot be created.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The Zip package 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' could not be loaded. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip'.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileStreamEx.CreateInstance(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare, Nullable`1 fileLength)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipFile.Load()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String path)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 106
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 56
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 71
2020-02-20 22:54:26,361 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Deployment failed: Unexpected Exception
2020-02-20 22:54:26,362 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [INFO]: Started Application Update
2020-02-20 22:54:26,362 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [ERROR]: Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception
```

> 2020-02-20 22:54:26,920 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of
>   Hook-EnactAppDeploy: Command hooks failed
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 544, in run_config
>         File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 138, in run_commands
>         File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 117, in apply
>       ToolError: Command hooks failed
>       2020-02-20 22:54:26,920 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
>       2020-02-20 22:54:26,920 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command hooks failed
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "cfn-init", line 171, in 
>         File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 129, in build
>         File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 530, in build
>         File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 544, in run_config
>         File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 138, in run_commands
>         File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 117, in apply

Comment: please check your iis application pool .net version and AWS Application Pool version.

Comment: using AppPool .NET 4.5 ...
although the app itself is technically running .NET 4.7.2 ... but for IIS everything => 4.5 just runs on AppPool 4.5

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe late but anyone experiencing this issue just check that in your repo you have aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json.

```
    {
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "deployments": {
    "aspNetCoreWeb": [
      {
        "name": "my-dotnet-core-app",
        "parameters": {
          "archive": "dotnet-core-app.zip",
          "iisPath": "/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Check this documentation from AWS
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-manifest.html

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)